# Why does my SVM using HOG features always predict the same class?

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, machine-learning, svm

I am trying to train SVM to predict the traffic sign, but I always get the same predict result for difference input image.

Can anyone explain why for me?

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/6y2MgTb8

I also print and compare the HOG value of test image and training image, it is the same, but why the predict result always are the same value.

Comment: How is the distribution of classes in the training data?

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
hog.compute(img_gray, descriptorsValues, Size(0, 0), Size(0, 0), locations);
//vector to Mat
Mat fm = Mat(descriptorsValues);

//Classification data
Ptr<SVM> svm = Algorithm::load<SVM>(nameSVM);
std::cout << "Model Loaded" << std::endl;

Mat image1d(1, fm.rows, CV_32FC1);
imshow("gradient 1", image1d);

float result = svm->predict(image1d);
```

You have accidentally created a new image empty (image1d) and used this uninitialized matrix for classification. Use the following call of svm prediction function instead:

```
float result = svm->predict(fm);
```

Comment: I have already tried this before. It will output the error : OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F) in cv::ml::SVMImpl::predict, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\ml\src\svm.cpp, line 1930. So i find the solution for this problem by convert "fm" to image1d.

Comment: can you check the size of your feature matrix fm how large is it?